# Trying to convert SQL getdate into varchar with no in-between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of auto-generated tables in MS-SQLServer that differ only in the date listed at the end of the name.
The challenge is that I want to create a script that always references a table 'x days back'.

So for example if the table name would be:
dbo.tablename_20200825

I can get "close" to the date format I need as a string with the following statement and style

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102);
```

[image]

However I still have those  periods of separation between each part of the date.

**How do I make the resulting string appear as '20200825' instead of '2020.08.25'**

Thank you as always for any insight and help.

Comment: Variable table names would require dynamic sql. This is generally a bad design.

Comment: The documentation on [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) gives you all the information you need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for 112

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112);
```

Results

```
20200825
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `format()` to get exactly what you want:

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd')
```